# Cloning $this to do chaining. Is it a bad idea?

Tags: php, chaining, method-chaining, cloning

I am having the following class:

```
class StuffDoer{
   public function __construct(Dep1 $dep, Dep2 $dep2, array $array){
      $this->dep = $dep;
      $this->dep2 = $dep2;
      $this->array  = $array;
   }

   public function genericDoStuff($param){
      // Do stuff here...
   }

   public function doStuffForMark(){
      return $this->genericDoStuff('Mark');
   }

   public function doStuffForTim(){
      return $this->genericDoStuff('Tim');
   }

   public function doStuffForAlice(){
      return $this->genericDoStuff('Alice');
   }
}
```

After some months, I am asked to make the method genericDoStuff($param), along with all the methods that depend on it, use an extra parameter in a single part of the application. Instead of changing the signature on every single method that depends on genericDoStuff, I ended up with the following:

```
 class StuffDoer{
   public function __construct(Dep1 $dep, Dep2 $dep2, array $array){
      $this->dep = $dep;
      $this->dep2 = $dep2;
      $this->array  = $array;
   }

   public function forParameter($param){
      $self = clone $this;
      $this->param = $param;
      return $self;
   }

   public function genericDoStuff($param){
      if($this->param !== null){
         // Do stuff by taking param into account
      } else {
        // Do stuff stuffdoer does
      }
   }

   public function doStuffForMark(){
      return $this->genericDoStuff('Mark');
   }

   public function doStuffForTim(){
      return $this->genericDoStuff('Tim');
   }

   public function doStuffForAlice(){
      return $this->genericDoStuff('Alice');
   }

}
```

That way, I am able to do this in the single point of the application:

```
$myStuffDoer = $serviceContainer->get('stuff_doer');
$myStuffDoer->forParameter('AAAARGHITBURNSGODHELPME')->doStuffForMark();
// Future usages of $myStuffDoer are unaffected by this!
```

So my question is this: Is this considered a bad practice for any reason?

Comment: Is it possible for you to make the argument optional? (`public function doStuff($param = null)`, change `if(this->param !== null)` to `if($param)`). I would not recommend your way, it is not clear for other developer and you create on every call of ::forParameter a new, cloned instance.

Comment: Agree with the optional argument. This is exactly what they're for.

Comment: The main reason I ended up with this (anti-pattern maybe), is that there are a lot other methods that depend on this specific one, and by design I'll have to set this optional parameter to every single one of them. If the code ends up being confusing, I'll consider doing so, but I'd like some opinions first.